# QThread how to use readwritelock on shared list in a tableview model?

Tags: locking, pyqt, qthread

i have a QTablewView which stores data as a List, the list is the backend data for a model.

```py
self.shots=[{'name':'abc010','taskdir','/show/abc/abc010','file':'xxx.ma'},
             {'name':'abc020','taskdir','/show/abc/abc020','file':'yyy.ma'},
              ...    ]
```

the `name, taskdir,file` attributes are from 3 seperate QThread, when i press a button, 3 threads are created and they get the result for the first element for my self.shots list, they run one by one,    then i hit the button a second time, another 3 threads returns the second element(a dictionary) in my list. and so one.

so essentially  my question is do i need to use read write lock in this case? my threads are writing to the same list,(because i may press the button a second time when the frist 3 threads are still running.)

current i'm getting segfault randomly without using any readwritelocks. is this the reason for crashing ?

thanks if anyone can give me a pseudo code about how to use the read write lock.

i'm using this generic thread function to create my threads.

```py
class GenericThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        # super(GenericThread, self).__init__()

        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self, *args):
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more code because it's not clear to me how the threads communicate.

Some remarks:

- You should store the data in the model, not in the view. That's the whole point of using a model/view design, it eliminates data consistency problems and makes it possible to have multiple views of the same model. [Qt Model/View Tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html)
- You should not subclass QThread, but instead use **moveToThread(QThread*)** to move an object with the required functionality to the thread. [How To Really, Truly Use QThreads](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)